# Density estimation vs estimation

Tags: machine-learning, density-estimation

Given a statistical model $(\mathcal{X},\Sigma,\mathcal{P})$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is a collection of probability measures on $\mathcal{X}$, and given a random sample with values in $\mathcal{X}$, we attempt to find the distribution from $\mathcal{P}$ that most closely agrees with the random sample. We assume each measure in $\mathcal{P}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to some reference measure, usually the Lebesgue measure.

My understanding is, in density estimation, the idea is to find some probability density function to associate to the random sample. How is this different, or more specific, than estimation generally? If we have the density $f$, we have a measure by integrating against $f$ (presumably with the Lebesgue measure). Conversely, if we have a measure $\mu\in\mathcal{P}$, taking the Radon-Nikodym derivative gives us a density. So what is it that distinguishes density estimation from general estimation?

Comment: "Non-parametric" is a good search keyword.

Comment: @whuber So is it, in parametric models, for each $\mu_{\theta}\in\mathcal{P}$ is parameterized by $\theta$ which we want to estimate, but otherwise we roughly know what $\mu_{\theta}$ is (for example, it's some gaussian with known variance)? So, in a parametric model, we roughly know the form of $\mu_{\theta}$ and therefore the density function $f_{\theta}$, but in non-parametric models, we don't even have an idea of what form $\mu$, or the density $f$ takes?

Comment: That's close to it.  In non-parametric models you might know something about the form but you cannot pin it down to a finitely parameterized family.